# update table in my project vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have datagridview show in it information from table name Customer_tbl 
Customer_id,Customer_code,CustomerFuulName,Customer_Address,Customer_phone,Customer_pic  when I want to update any Customer I send the information of current row in datagridview to EditCustomerForm by this code

```
Try
    With DGV_Customer_tbl
        EditCustomer.TxtCustomer_ID.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells("Customer_ID").Value.ToString()
        EditCustomer.TxtCustomer_Code.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells("Customer_Code").Value.ToString()
        EditCustomer.TxtCustomer_FullName.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells("Customer_FullName").Value.ToString()
        EditCustomer.TxtCustomer_Address.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells("Customer_Address").Value.ToString()
        EditCustomer.TxtCustomer_Phone.Text = .CurrentRow.Cells("Customer_Phone").Value.ToString()
        EditCustomer.PictureBox5.Image = DGVCurrentImageView(.CurrentRow.Cells("Customer_Pic").Value)
    End With
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

and every things ok I see all fields with image in the form but when I want to update any thing in the form and I dont change the Image an eroor Appears
like in the Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUuJH.jpg

but If I change Image every things go ok
my database type is access

Comment: Good luck with reading your own post :( , is this written in english ?

Comment: Don't provide screenshots of text. If you're executing code that throws an exception, post the code directly, post the error message directly (in English) and indicate where in the code it is thrown.

Comment: Also, don't save changes to the database from the edit dialogue. You should have a `DataTable` populated from the database using a data adapter or table adapter and bound to the grid. Any edits should be made to that `DataTable` and will thus be reflected in the grid immediately.  You then use the same adapter to save changes from the `DataTable` back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need the image data not as an image, but as binary data.  The output of this method is what should be what you pass to the parameter.

```
public static byte[] ImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image image)
{
    using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(ms, image.RawFormat);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I also don't think you are using AddWithValue properly.  In general, avoid it altogether, it makes assumptions on your data types.  Instead, explicitly define the data types of your parameters.